# pd.merge memory error

Tags: pandas

I have 2 data frames one with 3.2M rows and 12 columns (df_1) and other with 59K rows and 14 columns(df_2). pd.merge throws memory error. Tried lot of solutions listed under memory error **(Unable to allocate 100. GiB for an array with shape (13487872931,) and data type int64)**.I  tried the following instead of pd.merge

```
for val in df_1['ID'].unique():
    df1 = pd.merge(df_1[df_1['ID']==val], df_2, on='ID', how='left')
    dfs.append(df1)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
```

Comment: check that ``df1``does not have duplicate values on``ID``, if it has that's why the number of records is exploding to  13487872931, so delete duplicates on that column prior to merge. The loop is unnecessary so just do:``pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='ID', how='left')``

Comment: Thanks @Multivac, In this case df_1 has 3M products and the ID is category ID for the products, df_2 has contacts of the department heads and few POCs of the category. So df_1 has lot of duplicates in the ID column. I need the contacts and names to merged with all the product details on the key "ID". what would you suggest in this case?

Comment: is it possible to add a minimum reproducible example of your dataframes?